# Синхронизация остатков

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, woocommerce

Стоит следующая задача, может кто направит на путь истинный :)
Есть магазин, который работает в оффлайне. Будет разрабатываться интернет-магазин. Больше всего что на Woocommerce.
Задача:
Все остатки товара должны синхронизироваться. Если товар продался через интернет-магазин - изменения в базу данных внеслись и кол-во товара изменилось.
Тоже самое с кассовым аппаратом: в оффлайне товар продали, через кассу пропустили - в базе данных всё отобразилось. Как реализовать? Может есть какие-то готовые решения?
Такой сервис как CloudShop, условно, не подходит, так как у них это разные программы для оффлайна отдельно, для интернет-магазина отдельно и они не синхронизируются.

Comment: Для таких действий необходима интеграция ККМ с базой данных сайта. Вариантов много, начиная от 1С/Bitrix, и кончая специализированными разработками для различных типов рынков.

Comment: Спасибо. Может у кого ещё есть варианты... В этом вопросе я пока не особо разбираюсь, нужно понять глубину самой сути и может у кого есть готовое решение, клиент готов платить деньги...

Comment: Есть синхронизация WooCommerce с 1C

Comment: Что значит "как"? Нужен шлюз между  ВП/ЦС и неизвестной нам (но известной тебе) программой складского учёта.

Comment: Вам не стак нужен, а биржа фриланса.